# iPhone How to set up a view Upside Down mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4

We developed an app in Portrait mode, without acelerometer support.

We need, for usability, to turn 180º de app, so we need the app on Upside Down mode. We check in xib properties, if we found something magical to achive that...no way

any, clue? any help?

thanks in adavance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view controller needs to override `-[UIViewController  (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation]` and return YES for upside down portrait orientation.

Can't be done in IB.

Comment: if there are other view controllers loaded as part of the application, these must also implement this in order for it to work, you should also ensure that you set support interface orientations for your app

Comment: and there is any way to lock the app to Upside Mode only?

Comment: Return NO for unwanted orientations.

Comment: Because the answer is horribly outdated? Since iOS 6, use `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`

Answer (score 5):

As stated by Steven Kramer, define this in your view controller :

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    return YES to allow it or NO to forbid it
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    return YES to allow it or NO to forbid it
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    return YES to allow it or NO to forbid it
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    return YES to allow it or NO to forbid it
return NO; // Unknown value
}
```

If you only want to accept landscape mode for example, use

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

For portrait only, use `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);`